# Get Weekly Temperatures - ArrayList question

Tags: java, string, arraylist, int

I am a brand new beginner to any type of computer programming/language whatsoever (trying for a career change). I'm taking programming 1 through an online school and we use Zybooks (which I haven't found very helpful, so I've been using other resources). Here's the prompt for this week's homework:

Develop a Java program that will store data in the form of daily average temperatures for one week. Store the day and average temperature in two different arraylists. Your program should prompt the user for the day of the week (Monday through Sunday) and display both the day and temperature for each day. If “week” is entered, the output for your program should provide the temperature for each day and the weekly average. Use the looping and decision constructs in combination with the arrays to complete this assignment.

Below is the code I have so far. I'm just wondering if 1) I'm on the right track, and 2) how to print out my temps to match up with the weekday? I thought about doing an addList thing but won't that replace the week days with the temps? I have a lot of questions and I'm trying to find a tutor to help me. In the meantime, I figured I'd ask this community...esp since my online teacher ignores all my emails and questions. It's fun...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class weeklyTemps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NUM_TEMPS = 7;
        @SuppressWarnings("resource") //not sure where this came from...figure out later

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> weekDays = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> weekTemps = new ArrayList<>();

        String wkDay = "";
        int averageTemp = 0;
        int sumVal = 0;
        int i = 0;

            weekDays.add("Monday");
            weekDays.add("Tuesday");
            weekDays.add("Wednesday");
            weekDays.add("Thursday");
            weekDays.add("Friday");
            weekDays.add("Saturday");
            weekDays.add("Sunday");


            weekTemps.add(75); //temps for the week
            weekTemps.add(80);
            weekTemps.add(77);
            weekTemps.add(73);
            weekTemps.add(83);
            weekTemps.add(81);
            weekTemps.add(79);


            for (i = 0; i < weekDays.size(); ++i) { 
                System.out.print("Enter the week day: ");
                wkDay = scnr.nextLine();
            }

            for (i = 0; i < weekTemps.size(); ++i) {
                //sumVal = weekTemps //figure out how to add these together later w/out writing them all out
                averageTemp = sumVal / NUM_TEMPS;
            }

            if (wkDay.equals(weekDays())) {
                System.out.print("The temperature for that day is " + weekTemps.get(0) + " degrees.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("The average temperature for the week is " + averageTemp + " degrees.");
            }



return;

    }

    private static Object weekDays() { //what is this...i did not write this...
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<Integer> dayTemps = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> dayNames = new ArrayList<>();

            dayNames.add("Monday");
            dayNames.add("Tuesday");
            dayNames.add("Wednesday");
            dayNames.add("Thursday");
            dayNames.add("Friday");
            dayNames.add("Saturday");
            dayNames.add("Sunday");


            dayTemps.add(75); //temps for the week
            dayTemps.add(80);
            dayTemps.add(77);
            dayTemps.add(73);
            dayTemps.add(83);
            dayTemps.add(81);
            dayTemps.add(79);

            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the week day: ");
            String wkDay = scn.nextLine();
            scn.close(); //It is important to close the resources we use, preventing leak

            int indexOfWeekDay = dayNames.indexOf(wkDay); //get the in index of the day
            if(indexOfWeekDay != -1){ //if the name cannot be found, -1 is returned
                //User asked us about specific weekday:
                System.out.print("The temperature for " + dayNames.get(indexOfWeekDay) +" is " + dayTemps.get(indexOfWeekDay) + " degrees.");
            }else if(wkDay.equals("week")){
                //User asked us about average:
                //Only bother calculating average if asked ;)
                float averageTemp = 0; // I would recommend float for percision
                for (Integer dayTemp : dayTemps) { //This is called an enchanted for loop. I suggest looking it up ;)
                    averageTemp += dayTemp;
                }
                averageTemp /= dayTemps.size();
                System.out.print("The average temperature for the week is " + averageTemp + " degrees.");
            }else{
                //We can't recognise the entry
                System.out.println("Wrong entry: " + wkDay);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I have a couple questions tho if that's ok. First, can I close the scanner at the end of the program? Like all the way at the bottom? or does placement count? Also, why did you choose to move the Scanner to after the .add parts? Why would I use an indexOf() operation? I'll definitely look up an enchanted for loop since all we learned so far are while, do-while, and for loops. Do you think since I haven't learned the enchanted loop yet, that I should just stick to a regular loop? Is it super advanced java? Anyway, thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

2. Since the list is ordered and assuming the temperate at index 0 corresponds to Monday, you could do this;

```java
int indexOf = weekDays.indexOf(wkDay);

int temp = weekTemps.get(indexOf);
```

**Alternative**
1. Checks DayOfWeek
2. Edge-cases and validation
3. Uses recursion

```java
public class Temps {

    private static final List<DayOfWeek> days = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final List<Integer> temperatures = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        askUntilComplete();
    }

    private static void askUntilComplete() {
        while (days.size() < DayOfWeek.values().length) {
            ask("Enter a day of week: ");
        }
        printAverage();
    }

    private static void ask(String question) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(question);

        String input = scanner.next();

        try {
            DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.valueOf(input.toUpperCase());

            System.out.println("Enter a temperature for " + dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH));

            int temperature = scanner.nextInt();

            days.add(dayOfWeek);
            temperatures.add(temperature);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            System.out.println("This day does not exist.");
            ask(question);
        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("Weekday was ok but the temperature must be an integer.");
            ask(question);
        }
    }

    private static void printAverage() {
        System.out.println("The average temperature is: " + temperatures.stream().mapToInt(v -> v).average().orElse(0));
    }

}
```

**Alternative #2**
1. Uses a POJO to represent a daily temperature
2. Uses the equals/hashcode contract
3. Uses Set in combo with equals/hash to ensure 1 obj/day

```java
    public static class DailyTemperatureProgram {

        private static Set<DailyTemperature> dailyTemperatures = new HashSet<>();

        private static void askUntilComplete() {
            while (dailyTemperatures.size() < DayOfWeek.values().length) {
                ask("Enter a day of week: ");
            }
            printAverage();
        }

        private static void printAverage() {
            System.out.println("The average temperature is: " + dailyTemperatures.stream()
                    .mapToInt(v -> v.temperature).average().orElse(0));
        }

        private static void ask(String question) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println(question);

            String input = scanner.next();

            try {
                DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.valueOf(input.toUpperCase());

                System.out.println("Enter a temperature for " + dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH));

                int temperature = scanner.nextInt();

                dailyTemperatures.add(new DailyTemperature(dayOfWeek, temperature));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                System.out.println("This day does not exist.");
                ask(question);
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("Weekday was ok but the temperature must be an integer.");
                ask(question);
            }
        }

        private static final class DailyTemperature {

            private final DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;

            private final int temperature;

            private final int hashCode;

            private DailyTemperature(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, int temperature) {
                this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
                this.temperature = temperature;
                this.hashCode = Objects.hash(dayOfWeek);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object o) {
                if (o == this) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (o instanceof DailyTemperature) {
                    DailyTemperature other = (DailyTemperature) o;

                    return dayOfWeek == other.dayOfWeek;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I have a really dumb question but I seriously don't think we've gone over this in class...what is the difference between public and private static void? Does it matter what I choose to use? So far we've only used public. And also, what does "catch" mean? And last question...what is "HashSet"? Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Hey @Katelyn, not a dumb question at all. Public means that the method is accessible anywhere, where as private means the method is only accessible within the class.

Comment: Two part answer, too long. Private is useful when you don't want to, or don't need to, expose a method to outside of the class. Catch is a vital patch of the try-catch statement. A try-catch statement is called when a Throwable object is thrown. A HashSet is an implementation of Set that works specifically well with objects that implement the equals/hashcode contract. This is because until most other Collections that have a lookup of O(N), because of the hashcode we know the index so the lookup is O(1).